# Certain characters cause search to crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I realized that if you type `[user:1234]` in the search box, you get a white blank page. The site just errors out (It returns a `400 Bad Request`)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user%3a1234

Also: I just noticed that it strips off the last `]` in the query.

Also: I know the search term should be `user:1234` I just thought it would be better to provide some sort of error page, rather than just dumping a blank page.

**Update**: Here seems to be the list (so far) of what bricks it:

- `[test]` - works fine (redirects to tagged as test)
- `[anything:anything]` - bricks
- `[test:]` - bricks
- `[:test]` - bricks
- `[:]` - bricks

It seems that using the colon makes it explode. (giggity)

Comment: It happens when you search for [anything:likethis], for example [please:givemeablankpage].

Comment: It seems to work fine for `[test]` (it just redirects as if i typed `test` by itself)

Comment: Yes, there needs to be a : inside [] for the blank page to appear. The minimal search string that produces is is [:].

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the colon has some unusual behavior outside of just tags.

- If you do a search using a required term syntax with a colon (`+foo:bar`), this term behaves differently in two situations. If it is grouped with at least one non-tag term, it is treated as a literal term `+foo:bar` instead of a required term (so you'll look for things that actually contain the string `+foo:bar`). I believe enclosing it in quotes like `"foo:bar"` also treats the quotes as a literal component of the term.
- If the above search is not part of a mixed search (only tag terms or no other terms), then it is skipped and ignored. For example, `[foobar] +foo:bar` just yields all questions tagged `[foobar]`. If it is the only term, then it's a blank search and you go to Search Options.
- A mixed search with one tag search term that has a colon (say, `foobar [foo:bar]`) will be a proper mixed search: it will search for questions that have `foobar` and are tagged `[foo:bar]`. However, the presence of this colon will cause the behavior reported in the first scenario: `+` terms will be treated as literal terms. This means `+foobar [foo:bar]` returns questions with +foobar in them, and most interestingly `+[foo:bar]` returns all questions with + in them.

The conclusion is that the 400 error only shows up in "pure tag searches" which include a colon in at least one of the terms. However, there is some strange behavior induced by the first two cases. For purposes one reason or another, a term with a colon that is surrounded by quotes or prefixed by a + is treated as a tag search, even though legal advanced searches traditionally aren't. So the presence of `+foo:bar` or `"foo:bar"` will trigger a 400 error if it is grouped with a tag term with a colon, and a combination of just those searches will be treated as no search at all.